# Nilsson's sequence score for 8-puzzle problem in A* algorithm

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, search-algorithms, heuristics

I am learning the [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) on an 8-puzzle problem.

I don't have questions about A*, but I have some for the heuristic score -  Nilsson's sequence score.

[Justin Heyes-Jones web pages - A* Algorithm](http://www.heyes-jones.com/astar.html) explains A* very clearly. It has a picture for Nilsson's sequence scores.

[image: Nilsson's sequence scores]

It explains:

**Nilsson's sequence score**

> A tile in the center scores 1 (since it should be empty)
>
> For each tile not in the center, if the tile clockwise to it is not the one that should be clockwise to it then score 2.
>
> Multiply this sequence by three and finally add the total distance you need to move each tile back to its correct position.

I can't understand the steps above for calculating the scores.

For example, for the start state, what h = 17?

> 0 A C
>
> H B D
>
> G F E

So, by following the description,

`B` is in the center, so we have 1

Then `for each title not in the center, if the **tile** clockwise to **it** is not the one that should be clockwise to it then score 2.` I am not sure what this statement means.

What does the double starred `title` refer to?

What does the double starred `it` refer to?

Does the double starred `it` refer to the center title (B in this example)? Or does it refer to each title not in the center?

Is the next step that we start from `A`? So `C` should not be clockwise to `A`, then we have 2. And then `B` should be clockwise to `A`, then we ignore, and so on and so forth?

Answer (score 3):

See if this explanation can help you:

```
Current pos:   Goal:
*AC            ABC
HBD            H*D
GFE            GFE
```

How to calculate the score:

*Center*

```
B in the center -> 1
```

*Distances (manhattan distance)*

```
A must move LEFT -> 1
B must move UP   -> 1
sum of distances = 2
```

*Successors (clockwise)*

```
current: ACDEFGH*  (skip B because it is in the center)
goal:    ABCDEFGH

the [tile,tile clockwise to it] pairs  are:
[A,C], [C,D], [D,E], [E,F], [F,G], [G,H], [H,*]
([*,A] is not considered)

the "goal" pairs are:
[A,B], [B,C], [C,D], [D,E], [E,F], [F,G], [G,H], [H,A]
```

There are 2 pairs that do not match the goal pairs:

```
[A,C], [H,*]
```

So the final score is: $distances + 3*(center + 2*successors) = 2 + 3 * (1 + 2*2) = 17$